# Replacing the built-in script editor from QGIS with my own IDE (PyCharm)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pycharm

I have to do some scripting with pyqgis and would like to do this in my IDE 'PyCharm'. So I have set my python interpreter to the path C:/ProgramFiles/QGIS 3.28.3/bin/python-qgis.bat, so I can use the pyqgis library.

However, I need to be able to have access to a running QGIS App from Pycharm, as I need to be able to access active layers (which doesn't work in PyCharm yet, only from the in-built editor).

Is there a way to NOT use the in-built editor, but instead using PyCharm and still be able to access the running QGIS App?
The in-built editor must have a connection to the running App.

Is it possible to configure QGIS to use an external IDE/Script Editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `EDITOR` variable using:

`Settings > Options > System > Environment`

Enter here the path of your IDE.

[image]

Then, after a restart, clicking this button in the Script Editor window should open your IDE (with the current script if one exists).

[image]

Saving changes in either the IDE or the QGIS Script Editor will reflect in both applications.